# Why does GA shows 100% of my direct traffic are new users?

Tags: google-analytics

What could be the reasons for extremely high direct traffic? kind of unusual for me though.

GA shows 100% of my direct traffic are new users. Addition to that the total of direct traffic is much higher than organic traffic.

There are no errors in GA Debug.

Any help regarding this would be highly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please can you upload a screenshot of your Acquisition>All Trafic>Source/Medium report?

From the Source/Medium report, throw in a secondary dimension of Hostname and send a screenshot of that too (I recommend blurring or otherwise covering instances of your own Hostname).

Direct traffic is often an indication of an un-tagged email campaign, but you wouldn't expect that to generate 100% new traffic.

Other possibilities include spam, bot traffic, or perhaps traffic from your own company, or maybe a misapplication of the tracking code (for example, does your site cover multiple domain names?).

Comment: Thank you J Brazir]e, site got multiple domain names, I just checked and that is the reason